# Saving data in React Native

Tags: react-native

[Link to the File Structure Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fo1A.png)
So I'm currently learning React Native and assuming a file structure shown in the photo. I would like the user to click a button such that the button saves some text to a txt file under resources. How would I go about doing that?

I have tried AsyncStorage, fn-fetch-blob, react-native-filesystem but they have failed (not sure if those libraries are meant to be for specific file directories on your phone device)

What I have so far is a code shown below where if the user clicks the "Create file" button, then it saves to a text file called "my-file.txt" under the same directory as where the current .js file is, which well doesn't work

```
import FileSystem from 'react-native-filesystem'

export default class SaveData extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.createFile}>
                    <Text>Save to file</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    createFile = async () => {
        const fileContents = 'This is some content.';
        await FileSystem.writeToFile('./my-file.txt', fileContents);
    }
}
```

Comment: What failed when you used async-storage?? Try to use this;
https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: @mkEagles sorry bad wording, not failed but didn't do what I wanted it to do which is to store values in a text file. With AsyncStorage, as far as I understand it saves some key, value pair to some file. Do you know where I can refer to this file in my project directory?

Comment: Then if you want to store to a file, use https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob.

Comment: You can't refer to a file in your project if you're using async-storage

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is not possible. There is no way of accessing these directories when your app is running. This is not the same as when you are running on a computer (a node.js app for example). This file structure will not be available when you are running in a native environment.

`Async storage` is not used to save files. It is used to save values, so it will never work for what you are trying to accomplish here.

The closest thing to what you are trying to do would be to use `react-native-fetch-blob` and store the file in the file system of the device, which is also the correct way of storing a file on a mobile device.

Comment: Ok, that is fine, I don't mind storing a file in the file system of the device. Currently I am developing an iOS application and I'm not too familiar with how the file structure works. Is there like a directory you could suggest (I don't mind where I store the text files)

Comment: I am not sure about the file structure, especially on iOS. You can find more about it here `https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#user-content-file-system`. Also, you should probably use the package from this link since it has replaced `react-native-fetch-blob`.